# ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER & ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID in VC++ code

Tags: c++, winapi, parameters

I have written a routine that uses the [`HttpDeclarePush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/http/nf-http-httpdeclarepush) function from `Httpapi.dll` to utilize server pushes.

I am passing the parameters as below, but I am getting error 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) when calling `HttpDeclarePush()`:

```
const HTTPAPI_VERSION version = HTTPAPI_VERSION_2;
const auto request_queue_handle = reinterpret_cast<void*>(HttpCreateRequestQueue(version, nullptr, nullptr, 0, &p_req_queue_handle));

const auto verb = HttpVerbGET;
const auto http_path = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>("D:\Some_Path_From_Where_Resource_File_Will_Be_Pushed_To_Client\polyfills.0d74a55d0dbab6b8c32c.js");
const auto query = "polyfills.0d74a55d0dbab6b8c32c.js";

HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS* headers = nullptr;  //pHttpContext->GetRequest()->GetHeader; //lpOutBuffer;
const auto is_success = HttpDeclarePush(p_req_queue_handle, request_id, verb, http_path, query, headers);
```

I am not understanding which parameter is potentially the wrong one.  Can someone help me?

**EDIT:** Here is the modified code as you mentioned:

```
const auto request_queue_handle = HttpCreateRequestQueue(version, nullptr, nullptr, 0, &p_req_queue_handle);
const auto verb = HttpVerbGET;
const auto http_path = L"/polyfills.0d74a55d0dbab6b8c32c.js";
const auto query = nullptr;

HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS* headers = nullptr;  //pHttpContext->GetRequest()->GetHeader; //lpOutBuffer;

const auto is_success = HttpDeclarePush(p_req_queue_handle, request_id, verb, http_path, query, headers);
```

I was able to get past the earlier error, but now I am getting error 1229 (`ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID`) at `HttpDeclarePush(p_req_queue_handle, request_id, verb, http_path, query, headers);`

I have checked the JS file to be pushed. It is very much available in `https://localhost/polyfills.0d74a55d0dbab6b8c32c.js`.

Any help on this error? Is it that I need to provide some HEADERS in  `HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS* headers`? I tried something like `pHttpContext->GetRequest()->GetHeader;`, but I don't think that is the correct way of doing it.

Pardon me, I am new to VC++.

Comment: I see a problem with your path. You need to escape the \ or just use /

Comment: Also, your can't use `reinterpret_cast` to cast a narrow string literal to a wide string.  Get rid of the `reinterpret_cast` and use the `L` prefix instead: `const auto http_path L"D:\\Some_Path_From_Where_Resource_File_Will_Be_Pushed_To_Client\\polyfills.0d74a55d0dbab6b8c32c.js";`

Comment: And why are you `reinterpret_cast`'ing the return value of `HttpCreateRequestQueue()` to a `void*`? Get rid of that too, as the return value is not a queue handle, it is a status code. The last parameter is the actual queue handle: `HANDLE request_queue_handle; ULONG status = HttpCreateRequestQueue(..., &request_queue_handle);`

Comment: Also, the `Path` and `Query` parameters of `HttpDeclarePush()` are wrong anyway. The `Path` is NOT a local filesystem path, it is the "path portion of the URL for the resource being pushed". And the `Query` is the "query portion of the URL for the resource being pushed". So, if you were `GET`'ing something like `http://server/file.js`, the `Path` is `/file.js` and the `Query` is not present, whereas in something like `http://server/script?file.js`, the `Path` is `/script` and the `Query` is `file.js`

Comment: Can the last parameter be null? Documentation doesn't mention that.

Comment: Hi Raymond: Any idea what could be the C++ syntax to get the HEADERS and populate it at `HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS* headers`? I tried something like `pHttpContext->GetRequest()->GetHeader;` but I believe its incorrect.

Comment: You don't get the headers from somewhere. You make them yourself. Say what headers you want to be used in the HTTP request.

Comment: Do Headers have any role here in server push ? I mean if I am creating some header, how that's gonna be used ?

Comment: Overall it seems you're generally confused about how to use the API. Instead of trying things until they work, read the documentation to understand how the API is intended to be used. For example, the documentation for the `RequestId` parameter says "The request must be from the specified queue handle." Is the request from the specified queue handle? It doesn't look that way, since the queue handle was freshly-created and you haven't yet received a request.

Answer (score 0):

Header has to be created and passed properly as below:

```
HTTP_REQUEST_ID    request_id;
const HTTPAPI_VERSION version = HTTPAPI_VERSION_2;
auto pHttpRequest = p_http_context->GetRequest();
auto phttpRequestRaw = pHttpRequest->GetRawHttpRequest();
request_id = phttpRequestRaw->RequestId;
auto headers = phttpRequestRaw->Headers;

const auto is_success = HttpDeclarePush(p_req_queue_handle, request_id, verb, http_path, query, &headers);
```

`ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID` is the issue which is due one of the _`HTTP_HEADER_ID` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/http/ne-http-_http_header_id) parameter `HttpHeaderConnection`  taking `'Close'`, Hence the connection is closed after every request response.
Hence the bottom line is, we have to make the parameters proper to resolve ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.